# Reading in Excel file into array or list

Tags: c#, excel

So I have a HUGE excel file with headers, names, values stored.

I'm wanting to read everhting from row 5-95 and column A,B,C,D. I dont want to use a database I want to use a list or array.

What would be a way to read in the excel file and get the info I want?

Comment: What library are you using to read the excel file? What have you tried, where did you got stuck?

Comment: Here is the solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380/reading-excel-from-c Rgds,

Comment: I recommend using EPPlus if you have *.xlsx files: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: I would recommend using epplus https://epplus.codeplex.com if you do not have a library yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) Excel library.

For reading XLS files use this code:

```
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument();
List listRows = xls.easy_ReadXLSSheet_AsList("file.xls", "SheetName", "A5:D95")
```

For reading XLSX files use this code:

```
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument();
List listRows = xls.easy_ReadXLSXSheet_AsList("file.xlsx", "SheetName", "A5:D95")
```

The listRows will containg the rows and each of this rows is another list that contains the cell values.

Comment: What to i need to import to use Excel Document

Comment: You need to install EasyXLS, add a reference to EasyXLS.dll and import EasyXLS namespace. http://www.easyxls.com/manual/getting-started/easyxls-dot-net-excel-library.html